# Matching Values across multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server database with 6 tables.

Within these tables there is a a type of customer name.

- In Table One: Forename, Surname
- In Table Two: First Name, Second Name
- In Table Three: FirstName, Surname

etc etc across the 6 tables.

What I am trying to do is get a count of how many times:

- The full name (CONCAT of First and Last name) appears across all tables.
- The full name (CONCAT of First and Last name) appears across 5 tables
- The full name (CONCAT of First and Last name) appears across 4 tables
  etc etc
- The full name (CONCAT of First and Last name) only appears in table 1

Is there an easy way within SQL to do this type of thing??

Thanks

Comment: Unrelated to your specific question, but: if you perform other queries on the tables, be careful about when you concatenate column values (unless you are selecting them). The index can't be used for dynamic values. For example, this will use an index (if an index exists): `select * from table where first_name='John' and last_name='Doe'`, while this will not use an index `select * from table where concat(first_name, last_name)='JohnDoe')`. I only mention this because you have `CONCAT` explicitly stated in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a `union all` and `group by`.  The following does a bit more than you ask for.  It returns the number of times a name appears in each of the table.

You can easily simplify it for just the table count, if you like:

```
select t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, count(*) as cnt,
       min(fullname), max(fullname)
from (select fullname,
             sum(t1) as t1, sum(t2) as t2, sum(t3) as t3, sum(t4) as t4,
             sum(t5) as t5, sum(t6) as t6
      from ((select firstname +  ' ' + lastname as fullname,
                    1 as t1, 0 as t2, 0 as t3, 0 as t4, 0 as t5, 0 as t6
             from t1
            ) union all
            (select firstname +  ' ' + lastname as fullname,
                    0 as t1, 1 as t2, 0 as t3, 0 as t4, 0 as t5, 0 as t6
             from t2
            ) union all
            . . .
           ) t
       group by fullname
      ) f
group by t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon.
Struggling to make this work.

Should I be replacing **all** t1, t2 etc with the table names?? 

Just to test it out, i am just trying to get this to work with Table 1 (Customers) and Table 2 (CustSystem2) but can't see where I am going wrong. (Get 'Invalid Object Name' errors!)

Comment: @NewAtThis . . . You can add the table name before the alias, if you like:  `from Customers t1`, `from CustSystem2 t2`, and so on.  You need to fill in the `. . .` with the additional tables.

Comment: Think I am starting to get this - Just!!
Have created a DBFiddle to try and get the understand. 

[link](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=30310edeb1c0e14f946a82d4675ba037)

Comment: @NewAtThis . . . Here is a fixed version:  http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=1e5cb4de8b24c0ebe1c23a2407b6ec06.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this.

```
Select Name
      ,Hits=count(*)
      ,Tables = count(distinct Src)
 From (
        Select Src='Table1',Name=concat(FirstName,LastName) From Table1
        Union All
        Select Src='Table2',Name=concat(Foreame,SurName) From Table2
        Union All
        Select Src='Table3',Name=concat(FirstName,SurName) From Table3
        Union All
        ... Add more tables here
     ) A
 Group By Name
 Having count(*)>1
```

> **EDIT - Working Sample or [dbFiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=9e80fc47d6bc49ca19a3725cb4cf3eb5)**

```
Declare @Table1 table (FirstName varchar(50),LastName varchar(50))
Insert Into @Table1 values
 ('John','Smith')
,('Mary','Smith')

Declare @Table2 table (ForeName varchar(50),SurName varchar(50))
Insert Into @Table2 values
 ('John','Smith')
,('Mary-Ann','Jenson')


Select Name
      ,Hits=count(*)
      ,Tables = count(distinct Src)
 From (
        Select Src='Table1',Name=concat(FirstName,LastName) From @Table1
        Union All
        Select Src='Table2',Name=concat(ForeName,SurName) From @Table2
     ) A
 Group By Name
 Having count(*)>1
```

**Returns**

```
Name        Hits    Tables
JohnSmith   2       2
```

Comment: Thanks John.
When changing 'Table1' to the actual table name of 'Customers' I just get invalid object name errors.

Comment: @NewAtThis Did you sync the Field Names as well per table.   Without the actual Table names and associated field names, I could only supply an illustrations....  fyi Src could be any distinct value i.e 1 - 6

Comment: @NewAtThis This is an illustration on http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=9e80fc47d6bc49ca19a3725cb4cf3eb5 Only created two tables, but demonstrates that the appoach works